# passing data between views using tabBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, expression, uitabbar

Ok, so I have part of my app that i'm working on passing float variables between views and everything was fine, but with all the button it looked a bit messy. and being so that i am nearly finished I wanted to see if i could add a tabBar to the existing view and clean it up. I found a great tutorial on this and got it to link up and report what tab i was selecting in NSLog so went ahead and pasted the code I had for the button I used to use for the same function. everything went a little funny and i had to make some new variables and i'm down to one last error that I cant figure out.
 It is calling for an expected expression for the first time i call patternRafter

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);

[self activateTab:item.tag];
}

- (void)activateTab:(int)index {
switch (index) {
    case 1:

        patternRafter *patternRafter1 = [[patternRafter  alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        BuildNavAppDelegate *buildNavDelegate = (BuildNavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        buildNavDelegate.TLPMR = [TLMR text];
        buildNavDelegate.comRaftBirdPassed = [comBird text];
        buildNavDelegate.comRaftLengthPassed = [comRafter text];
        buildNavDelegate.raftThicknessPassed = [rafterWidth text];



        [self presentModalViewController:patternRafter1 animated:YES]; 
        break;
    /*case 2:

        buildersSquare *square1 = [[buildersSquare alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        BuildNavAppDelegate *buildNavDelegate = (BuildNavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        buildNavDelegate.TLPMR = [TLMR text];
        buildNavDelegate.comRaftBirdPassed = [comBird text];
        buildNavDelegate.comRaftLengthPassed = [comRafter text];
        buildNavDelegate.raftThicknessPassed = [rafterWidth text];



        [self presentModalViewController:square1 animated:YES];         
        break;
    case 3:

        self.tab2ViewController =[[tab2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"tab2" bundle:nil];
        [self.view insertSubview:tab2ViewController.view belowSubview:tabbar1];
        if (currentViewController != nil)
            [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        currentViewController = tab2ViewController;         
        break;*/
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

any help would be appreciated. thanks
and I just realised I can't post pictures because i'm still a new user. so here is a link if anyone feels like checking it out.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72193343/Screen%20shot%202012-05-18%20at%209.22.48%20AM.png

Comment: sorry, i have been seeing this on other posts just recently and now i know how, thankyou.

Comment: no worries. Did that answer work for you?

Comment: no that answer didn't work. But I understand now what he means. this was my first attempt at an app and the start was pretty sloppy, so just for this one I have continued with the bad habits just to keep it working. I did however find some help elsewhere that solved the problem but left me with some warnings still. I cant answer my own question for another 2 hours as I am still a new user.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that patternRafter is an instance of a class named PatternRafter? If so, that line needs to look like this:

```
PatternRafter *patternRafter1 = [[PatternRafter alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Obj-C is case sensitive and naming conventions call for ivars to begin with lower case and classes to begin with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)activateTab:(int)index {
switch (index) {
case 1://igot it to work by opening brackets here{

    patternRafter *patternRafter1 = [[patternRafter  alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    BuildNavAppDelegate *buildNavDelegate = (BuildNavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    buildNavDelegate.TLPMR = [TLMR text];
    buildNavDelegate.comRaftBirdPassed = [comBird text];
    buildNavDelegate.comRaftLengthPassed = [comRafter text];
    buildNavDelegate.raftThicknessPassed = [rafterWidth text];



    [self presentModalViewController:patternRafter1 animated:YES]; //local declaration of 'patternRafter1' hides instance variable
    break;//and closing here} 
case 2:
```

its working fine but i am receiving warning for -- local declaration of 'patternRafter1' hides instance variable